# Device unable to detect emoji into received push notification

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]

No idea why device not detecting emoji which I am getting into push notification from server, But I am able to convert emoji unicode in to emoji to show on text view or label. Below is the code:

`NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *newMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding]`

Comment: Please suggest me, what i should do.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue with Code in php because we are not decoding the message, Please see the adde code:

```
$string = "The fact \ud83d\ude05"; 
$message = json_decode('"'.$string.'"');
```

And now device able to detect emoji